# Viewing files in a remote FTP folder from a webpart

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, ftp, moss

We're looking to integrate a file/folder view of a FTP share in a SharePoint portal. We recon the best solution would be to create a webpart that reads the contents of the FTP share and displays it in the portal.

Is there any third party solutions for this? Has anyone done anything like this before.. and might be able to give us some pointers to things to watch out for?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you just want to view the files oder do you want to access them too? Or even upload files over the web part?

Comment: I would just like to view them

Answer (score -1):

under linux You can:
1. mount ftp like network disk and browse local dir
2. may You can call external ftp for it